# How to use the values returned by one select subquery, in the main query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to write a sql query to return the number of employees who's weighted average of their achievement is in the respective ranges (0 - 25 or 25 - 50 or 50 - 75 or 75 - 100), in one single query.

For example, this is the data in my table.

```
emp_id   task_id    weightage   achievement
emp01    task11     40          105
emp01    task12     30          0
emp01    task13     20          10
emp01    task14     10          10
emp02    task21     90          0
emp03    task31     50          45
emp03    task32     50          50
```

The result should be like this (this should be the output of the single query) :

```
range_of_weighted_average       no.of_employees
0-25                            1
25-50                           2
50-75                           0
75-100                          0
```

The result is like this because, the weighted average of emp01's achievement is 45, emp02's is 0 and emp03's is 47.50. So, according to the records in the table there are two employee's whose weighted average of achievement is in the range 25-50 and one in 0-25 range and there are no others in the rest of the ranges, so 0.

I wrote this query to find the weighted average of each employee's achievement

```
select emp_id, sum(weightage * achievement) / sum(weightage) as weighted_avg_emp
from table_name
group by emp_id;
```

This results :

```
emp_id     weighted_avg_emp
emp01      45.0000
emp02      0.0000
emp03      47.5000
```

**Just as a summary of what the query should return :**
For the table above, should write a single query that would return the output with `range_of_weighted_average` & `no.of_employees`.

I was able to write the query till calculating weighted avg of each employee but I'm not being able to figure out how to use this results in the same query to find out the no.of employees in range.

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Your expected output might be slightly off, as it seems your original table has _3_ employees in it, not 2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, sorry. I forgot to consider 0. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT emp_id, SUM(weightage * achievement) / SUM(weightage) AS w_avg
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY emp_id
),
ranges AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, '0 - 25' AS rng UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '25 - 50' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '50 - 75' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '75 - 100'
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN w_avg < 25 THEN '0 - 25'
             WHEN w_avg < 50 THEN '25 - 50'
             WHEN w_avg < 75 THEN '50 - 75'
             ELSE '75 - 100' END AS rng,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT
    r.rng AS range_of_weighted_average,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.cnt), 0) AS no_of_employees
FROM ranges r
LEFT JOIN cte2 t
    ON t.rng = r.rng
GROUP BY
   r.rng,
   r.id
ORDER BY
    r.id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I like this approach, but I think you have a typo in the CTE `ranges`. Shouldn't the first column be 3 and 4 for the 3rd and 4th rows?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why the `ranges` CTE is even needed. Couldn't you just use the query in `cte2` to get the result? The group by already results in one row for each range, so I don't think the `SUM` is doing anything extra.

Comment: @patrick3853 Good catch, and yes, the `ranges` CTE is needed, because if the OP's data has not any data for one of the 4 particular ranges, then without this CTE, such a zero count range would not be appearing the final report (note that your query does not suffer from this problem, because you union together the counts for each range).

Comment: Oh yes, I see. That's why you use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to ensure each range is in the result.